# VB Classic Windows Service says UNC file does not exist, works on 2nd server

Tags: vb6, windows-services, unc

I have a VB Classic Windows service on two different 2008 Servers that access the same folder on a 2012 Server.  Both 2008 servers are configured the same (something's probably not) running the same application software.  One application can access the UNC files fine, the same application on the other server says the file doesn't exist and always returns false using objFSO.Exists(UNCfilename).  I can't see the difference in the servers and have exhausted places to look.  Here's some more background:

- Both services running as administrator
- Running services in VB as administrator, one fails one doesn't
- UNC Folders on 2012 are shared with Everyone, full control
- All servers on same subnet
- All servers running workgroup not domain
- All Firewalls are off
- I can see UNC folder and files using Windows Explorer on both servers
- C# services running as administrator on both servers see the files (no, converting the VB service to C# is not an option)
- Dir(UNCfilename) doesn't work either on the one server, does on the other

There must be a difference in the two 2008 servers but I don't know what it could be.  What have I missed?

Comment: When you're checking in Windows Explorer are you certain you're using the same users & permissions as what the VB software is running as?

Comment: It might be something like https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035277

Comment: That article had promise but it was already set to elevate without prompting.  I've logged on as administrator and am running the app in VB as administrator.  When it runs as a service, I've set the user to administrator.

Comment: The key thing I once learned from that article is how Windows tokens work. In the situation I was dealing with, running as admin actually gave the process LESS access - because the drive had been mapped as an ordinary user instead of as admin, and admin didn't "inherit" the map without the registry change. This seemed totally counter-intuitive until I understood it. Maybe it doesn't apply in your situation however.

Comment: At this point, ANYTHING is worth looking at.   Your comments make sense. But to the best of my knowledge, we don't use any mapped drives.  However, I will definitely take a look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution... don't exactly understand why this was the only fix I found, but after all this time, I don't much care!

DaveInCaz's comments about mapped drives led me in the right direction.  We didn't have any but I wondered what would happen if we did.  I added the following code to the program:

```
remoteUser = "Administrator"
remoteServerName = "CADERed5" 'The name of the 2012 server
myUNCPath = "\\192.168.100.4\c\Program Files (x86)\..."

Set NetworkObject = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "", myUNCPath, False, remoteServerName & "\" & remoteUser, remotePassword
If objFSO.FolderExists(myUNCPath) Then
...
```

I had to use the credentials of the target (2012) server's administrator prefixed by the server's name.  Basically, I became that server's admin and it allowed me to read the files.